# How to protect site path in nginx?

Tags: security, nginx

I need to protect site path like site.com/logger by using ngix. How shoul I do that correctly? What's the best practices?

Password protection or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ^~ /path-to-dir {deny all}
```

or

```
location /path-to-dir {
auth_basic           "closed site";
auth_basic_user_file /full-path-to-htpasswd;
}
```

Comment: Is auth_basic secure enough? And how to protect against search bots like google and any?